# OpenCl watchdog in linux

Tags: linux, opencl, watchdog

Earlier I used to develop OpenCl kernels on a Windows system, and now I use a Linux one. On Windows there is a neat feature called watchdog which automatically stops the OpenCl computation if it lasts more than 5 seconds (by default), and it's very helpful in case of some mistake in code which causes a very long or infinite run. Is there a way to achieve something like this in Linux?

I have an AMD Mobility graphic card, and latest AMD drivers for it. If there is no possibility to have a watchdog, is there a way to terminate OpenCl kernel manually?

Comment: It might depend upon your OpenCL implementation.... (Do you use AMD/FGLRX or Nvidia ...)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: I use AMD one, and the graphic card itself is AMD.

Answer (score 1):

Nvidia's X11 drivers on Linux do include a watchdog which is on by default.  It's controlled by an "Interactive" flag in the xorg.conf.  See "Option 4" [here](http://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3029/~/using-cuda-and-x).

Since it's Nvidia-driver specific, the solution for AMD will be different (if there is one).